# как сохранить результат этого парсинга в excel таблицу?

Tags: python, excel, export

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("https://krisha.kz/arenda/kvartiry/almaty/")


responce = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a-card__header')
for result in check:
    link = result.find('a', href=True)
    print(result.text.strip())
    if link:
        print("https://krisha.kz" + link['href'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку pandas для сохранения результатов в файл Excel. Вот как вы можете это сделать:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://krisha.kz/arenda/kvartiry/almaty/"

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
check = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'a-card__header')

results = []
for result in check:
    link = result.find('a', href=True)
    text = result.text.strip()
    if link:
        link = "https://krisha.kz" + link['href']
    results.append([text, link])

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Text', 'Link'])
df.to_excel('results.xlsx', index=False)
```

В этом коде мы создаем список `results`, в который добавляем пары [текст, ссылка]. Затем мы преобразуем этот список в DataFrame и сохраняем его в файл Excel с помощью метода `to_excel`. Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что у вас установлен пакет `openpyxl`, который требуется для записи файлов Excel. Если он не установлен, вы можете установить его, используя команду **`pip install openpyxl`**.

Comment: Спасибо большое